# Using youtube API in asp.net mvc

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4, youtube

I've a website built on asp.net mvc.I would like to include the videos from my youtube channels using youtube API.What's the best way to embed videos in a website from YOUTUBE using YOUTUBE API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since January 2015 Youtube recommends to embed the videos using an iframe: [see doc here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp).

Once you get the api video list from `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos`, all the video ids are placed within the items object response.

From there you would do something as follows:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{YOUR_VIDEO_ID_HERE}}?autoplay=1">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thank You for your response